# Getting lots of marked JCheckBoxes on a new JPanel?

Tags: java, checkbox

I have a long List of Checkboxes (about 150) on a JPanel on a scrollPane, the user can check if needed. At the end of this Process there is a JButton, which should take all the marked Checkboxes and put their description on a different JPanel. I am pretty new to Java and can't figure out, how to do this without creating an itemListener for every Checkbox, which just seems very unpractical. I've read a lot of threads about putting the Checkboxes into an ArrayList and checking the elements, but I still don't understand how to do this. My Current Code looks something like this:

```
JCheckBox checkbx511 = new JCheckBox("This is the text I need");
chckbx511.setToolTipText("<html>This would be a nice bonus</html>");
```

Anybody know an easy way to get all the selected Elements on a new List?

Comment: Iterate the list and call `isSelected()` on each one?

Comment: Note : a lot of smilar code -> should iterate a collection. Here you should store those checkbox into a List (using a loop to generated those). And the use Kayaman idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the descriptions for the checkboxes in an array and then create a list of check boxes, something like this:

```
// Creating checkboxes
String[] descriptions = { "Description 1", "Description 2", "Description 3"};
List<JCheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
for (String description : descriptions) {
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(description);
    checkBoxes.add(checkBox);
    jPanel.add(checkBox);
}
```

Then when you press the button you simply iterate over the list of checkboxes to find out what boxes are selected and add them to your new panel.

```
// On button press
for (JCheckBox checkBox : checkBoxes) {
    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
        otherJPanel.add(new JLabel(checkBox.getText()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a `List`

```
List<JCheckBox> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you need to store those checkbox into this list. You either add every one by and

```
list.add(checkbx511);
```

or change the way you build those to use a loop (the text could be in a `String[]` to iterate this)

Then, to get the selected checkbox, you just need to iterate your new list and check if it is selected with `CheckBox.isSelected()`. You store those instance into a other List and you have your result.

```
List<JCheckBox> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
for(JCheckBox cb : list){
    if(cb.isSelected()){
        resultList.add(cb);
    }
}
```

Note : There is a way to do this in Stream API but I will let someone else to write it because I don't know it enough.

Note 2 : There is a complicated way without using a List by searching into a JPanel componenent every JCheckBox instance. But this needs a know structure to be written

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer! I should be able to implement this.

Comment: @Lotec, if you have problem about this solution, don't hesitate to ask. See Sore Throad answer about my solution to create the Checkbox in a loop, I didn't add this since this was not really needed